# Trying to sort an array of objects but splice is not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The global picture is that i am trying to remove duplicates from an array of objects. Objects with the same advertId and leadboxId are considerd duplicates but for testing purposes i am only checking advertIds

I am getting this array from the sessionStorage and removing duplicates.

```
var testSort = function () {
    var events = [];
    events = sessionStorage.events;
    console.log("events unsorted");
    console.log(events);
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        for (var x = i + 1; x < events.length; x++) {
            if (events[x].advertId == events[i].advertId) {
                events.splice(x, 1);
                --x;
            }
        }
        // add
    }
```

The console prints out the events array as such:

```
[{"module":"slick_module","eventType":"swipe","leadboxId":"1565","advertId":"5653","length":"length of event","time":1462783354789,"posted":"postedStatus"},{"module":"slick_module","eventType":"swipe","leadboxId":"1565","advertId":"56527","length":"length of event","time":1462783357590,"posted":"postedStatus"}]
```

Is this not a good array?
When trying to splice this i get the error that events.splice is not a function.

Any help is aprecciated.

Comment: Er... Did you check if `events` is not null?

Comment: It is the same event i am logging above and it seems to still be filled before i splice it.

Comment: When you splice in a for loop you must take care of all shifting indexes. You best use `Array.prototype.filter()`.

Comment: Using nina's code below i still have the same problem. It seems that what i am using is not an array? The console.log looks like an array and when i add the events to the sessionStorage.events i add an array but it wont let met use any array functions on it

Comment: for testing, you can perform an output with `Array.isArray(sessionStorage.events)` and check if the variable is an array or not.

Comment: check `typeof events === 'array'`. I guess sessionStorage stores variable as string only

Comment: It isnt an array. As Hank pointed out i forgot that i have to convert it back into an array. Thanks everyone for the help. Still new to using sessionStorage. I will mark Romans answer as that is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store an array/object in **SessionStorage**. 
Web storage can only store strings.
 You have a string in the `sessionStorage['events']` key, processed via `JSON.stringify()` method.
 To deal with array for further filtering - decode that string with `JSON.parse()` method like:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['events']);
...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Yes i forgot about this. Hank had just pointed this out before you. But yours is the only answer with the solution so i am going to accept this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a hash table for already inserted elements.

```js
var array = [{ "module": "slick_module", "eventType": "swipe", "leadboxId": "1565", "advertId": "5653", "length": "length of event", "time": 1462783354789, "posted": "postedStatus" }, { "module": "slick_module", "eventType": "swipe", "leadboxId": "1565", "advertId": "56527", "length": "length of event", "time": 1462783357590, "posted": "postedStatus" }, { "module": "slick_module", "eventType": "swipe", "leadboxId": "1565", "advertId": "56527", "length": "length of event", "time": 1462783357590, "posted": "postedStatus" }],
    filtered = array.filter(function (a) {
        var key = a.leadboxId + '|' + a.advertId;
        if (!this[key]) {
            this[key] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This returns the same error but this time with filter? For some reason my array isnt seen as an array? but the console output seems to indicate it is an array

Answer (score 0):

As always `Array.prototype.reduce()` to help with a single liner

```js
var events = [{"module":"slick_module","eventType":"swipe","leadboxId":"1565","advertId":"5653","length":"length of event","time":1462783354789,"posted":"postedStatus"},{"module":"slick_module","eventType":"swipe","leadboxId":"1565","advertId":"56527","length":"length of event","time":1462783357590,"posted":"postedStatus"}],
  filtered = events.reduce((p,c) => !~p.findIndex(e => e.advertId == c.advertId) ? p.concat(c) : p, []);
document.write("<pre>" +  JSON.stringify(filtered, null,2) + "</pre>");
```